# K8s Nginx Proxy not reaching Pod

Tags: apache, docker, nginx, proxy, kubernetes

I am having issues connection my wordpress Pod to an nginx proxy pod that is public. The Main issue I'm having is:  `*1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`

I have my docker container that is setup to mimic a LAMP stack exposing port 80 and inside the container my apache conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog /var/log/error.log
CustomLog /var/log/acces.log combined

<Directory /var/www/html>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From the pod deployment I have the container port set to 80 as well, this is the section of the kubernetes deployment that exposes that port

```
ports:
- containerPort: 80
  name: http
```

And on the service for the pod i have it selecting that deployment pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: project-legacy-wp
  labels:
    app: project
    role: legacy-wp
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: project
    role: legacy-wp
```

Finally my nginx proxy looks like this and this is where I am a little shaky. I am not familiar with nginx proxies and I did not set this up. I tried my best to get it similar to the other sites in the cluster

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers         'CIPHERS';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_certificate     path/to/certs;
    ssl_certificate_key path/to/certs;

    server_name         example.com;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    location / {
      access_log on;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_buffering off;
      proxy_pass http://project-legacy-wp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the LAMP `pod` via the linked `service` with its name which is accessible per DNS (in a common Kubernetes setup). I.e. set

```
server {
    # ...
    location / {
      # ... 
      proxy_pass http://project-legacy-wp;
    }
}
```

Also check if

```
kubectl get endpoints project-legacy-wp
```

shows one endpoint, i.e. the internal IP of your pod.

If not, then check that the `label`s in your `deployment` under

```
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: APP_NAME
```

are the same as the `label`s in the `service`'s `selector`:

```
spec:
  selector:
    app: APP_NAME
```

Comment: I have this currently set like that. I edited the server to have a different pod name. Is there a different way to check if its accessible through the service? I'm suer new to k8s and this was kind of dumped on me

Comment: @PabloMarti Oh, ok. Then check the `endpoint`s and `selector` as described in my updated answer.

Comment: thank you for your help but, it seems to be all correct with what you were saying. Yet I'm still getting a time out error.

Comment: @PabloMarti So, you're getting "timeout"s instead of "connection refused"? That sounds more like a firewall problem then. Try `curl -v ENDPOINT_IP` at your host.

Comment: *   Trying 10.55.253.194...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.55.253.194 (10.55.253.194) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.55.253.194
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
< Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0

Comment: < Pragma: no-cache
< Set-Cookie: wfvt_234879947=5a8c393050075; expires=Tue, 20-Feb-2018 15:35:20 GMT; Max-Age=1800; path=/; HttpOnly
< Location: http://10.55.253.194:80/
< Content-Length: 0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0

Comment: Seems ok, couldn't format it correctly through the comments.

Comment: I don't know if I was supposed to tag you @Dominik

Comment: @PabloMarti Your Apache server resp. Wordpress is redirecting to the same IP. That's strange. Maybe this helps: [Redirect loop with Wordpress on Apache with nginx reverse proxy and HTTPS on Ubuntu 16](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirect-loop-with-wordpress-on-apache-with-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-https-on-ubuntu-16)